# How to set GridLayout Params to a GridLayout where the views are added dynamically?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, android-gridlayout

With my app, I'm adding buttons dynamically per floatactionbutton click so my buttons are generated through Java.  I have set the RelativeLayoutParams for my buttons' dimensions when it is in portrait mode but I need to do the same for when it is in Gridlayout @ landscape mode but I couldn't figure out how to set up the GridLayout.  There is also an issue with my floatactionbutton, where when its clicked as the views exceed the screen size, the button scrolls down as well.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

This is my Java.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter = 0;

    FloatingActionButton addingSemester;
    Button semesterButton;
    LinearLayout semesterLayout;
    GridLayout semesterGridLayout;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams portraitLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
        semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        semesterGridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.semester_grid_layout);
        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.delete) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeAllViews();
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        if (counter < 8) {
            semesterButton.setId(counter + 1);
            semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (counter + 1));
            semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            portraitLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);

            if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
            } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
                semesterButton.setLayoutParams(portraitLayoutParams);
            }

            // these lines moved outside the if statement blocks
            counter++;
            setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();

        } else if (counter == 8) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton() {
        semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Button b = (Button) v;
                b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                b.setText("Delete");

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeView(b);
                                }
                                counter--;
                                for (int i = 0; i < semesterGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                    ((Button) semesterGridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                b.cancelLongPress();
                                b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my XML for the landscape mode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/semester_grid_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity">


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/addActionButton"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onFloatActionButtonClick"
                android:longClickable="true"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp" />

    </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you have a relatively small number of views that can be added, which it looks like you are limiting yours to 8, it might be easier to create all of the views in XML, but set their visibility to GONE.  Then, when the user clicks the button, just set the visibility to VISIBLE.

Comment: The thing is I'm going to have this dynamic view addition a lot later on so it would be expensive to do that.